# How to use multiple "Contact Us" forms (now that it cannot be called in CMS)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, cms-pages, contact-form

My site used to have a Contact Us CMS page which called the standard "Contact Us" form and a Returns CMS page which called a very slightly edited template of the form.

It is now apparently impossible to call the contact form via the CMS/Static Blocks without breaking the page:

{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}

Does anyone know how to recreate this simple functionality?

Both my forms just go through to the same email address, and use the same email template.

I just want to use the form twice :(

Any help appreciated